# Delete Cookie in Multiple Action Request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, request, response

I want to delete cookie in ASP.NET

This is the code I am using and it is working fine for all scenario except from one.

```
   public static void DeleteCookie(string name)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];

                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    // Delete the cookie
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
            }
        }
```

And the scenario is this.

A cookie is created when I go to the detail page of my item. When I go back to the item list. Then I need to delete the cookie so some menu does not show up. But in the same request when View call that deleted cookie it returns the save value.

I have debugged the cookie. The expire date ie being set to -ve but the until the request is not complete the cookie is not deleted.

Help..

Comment: I think you are checking the cookie in server side in the same request you try deleting. I would ask you to check for expiry data also while you check for showing the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are stored client-side, so the cookie isn't actually deleted until the client gets the response header directing it to. Then, on the *next* request, it will no longer send that cookie, but you cannot delete and check that it's been deleted in the same request, since it actually has not been deleted yet. Generally, when you delete a cookie, you want to return a redirect, even if it's to the same URL. That way, the client will be forced to make a new cookie-less request.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detailed explanation, Actually I figure that out before if post this question. Just wanted to know if there is a way to bypass it. So when I had no luck. I set the value of the Cookie to null where I delete the cookie. That do the trick for me.